# AccountKitLoginResult removed from latest version of Facebook's Account Kit SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, account-kit

The reference page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/4.11/interface/AccountKitLoginResult/ for `AccountKitLoginResult` mentions that

> This class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK

. There are two problems with it.

1. If this interface has been / is going to be removed, there is no mention of what to use instead of this interface to extract the result of an Account Kit login action from the returned Intent in `onActivityResult` callback.
2. On downloading the latest version of Account Kit SDK, I found that the interface is still there, alive and kicking. So why is this warning on the facebook reference page there?

Comment: i don't find any warning on the facebook reference page ...about `AccountKitLoginResult`..can u provide a link..?

Comment: I have added the link.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're seeing the old reference. The new one sends you to:
[Accoun Kit Login Result - New Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/AccountKit/com/facebook/accountkit/accountkitloginresult.html/)